# Going to the first page of a chapter/issue

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm developing a webcomic using django. I'm trying to implement a feature that if you click on a comic issue or chapter cover it will redirect you to the first page of that issue/chapter.
[Picture for a reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgfFO.png)

Here is what I have managed to do so far.

**models.py**

```
class PagePL(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Page number', unique=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    issue = models.ForeignKey(IssuePL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pages')
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(ChapterPL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField('Page image', upload_to=get_image_pl_filename, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def ComicPagePL(request, slug, number):
    comic_page_pl = get_object_or_404(PagePL, chapter__slug=slug, number=number, status=1)
    context = {
        'comic_page_pl': comic_page_pl,
        }
    return render(request, 'comics/comic_page_pl.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('comics/', views.IssueListPL, name='comics_pl'),
    path('comics/<slug>/<number>', views.ComicPagePL, name='comic_page_pl'),
]
```

**issue list template**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 mt-3">
        {% if issue_pl %}
        {% for issue in issue_pl %}
            <a href="#"><img src="{{ issue.cover.url }}" class="issue-thumbnail" alt="{{ issue.title }}" title="{{ issue.title }}" /></a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p style="text-align:center">BRAK ZESZYTÓW</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when you go to .../chapter-slug/page-number it works. I would like to make it that if you click on issue one it goes to the first page of issue one and if you click on issue two it goes to the first page of issue two.

Probably some filter will do the work, but I'm trying different combinations with no luck so far.

**UPDATE**

I have made a little progress, however I'm still not quite there.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 mt-3">
        {% if issue_pl %}
        {% for issue in issue_pl %}
            <a href="{% url 'comic_page_pl' issue.slug issue.number %}"><img src="{{ issue.cover.url }}" class="issue-thumbnail" alt="{{ issue.title }}" title="{{ issue.title }}" /></a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p style="text-align:center">BRAK ZESZYTÓW</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

With this when I click on the issue 1 cover it goes to .../first-issue-slug/1, when I click on issue 2 cover it goes to .../second-issue-slug/2 and so on. I know that is how the loop is built. I need to figure out how to make it that when I click on issue 1 it will go to the first page of that issue and when I click on issue 2 it will go to the first page of issue 2 etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to finally go further. The solution was the below model function:

```
 def first_page_url(self):
    page = PagePL.objects.filter(issue=self).first()
    if page is None:
        return None
    return reverse('comic_page_pl', args=[page.chapter.slug, page.number])
```